# setlocale() for LC_MESSAGES to non-existing locale fails

Tags: c, localization, glibc, setlocale

For an embedded software project, I am adding support for translations and since we are running an embedded Linux I went for using libc `gettext()`. We do not have any locale definitions whatsoever installed, so I only try to set the `LC_MESSAGES` locale to my desired locale:

```
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "fake");
```

(I am using the name `fake` with a `fake.mo` file to do a pseudo-translation before I get my hands on proper translations).

This works fine when linked statically, it returns a locale handle, `bindtextdomain()` and friends all work fine and I get my "translated" string out of it:

```
setlocale() returned "fake"
current textdomain is "ewe"
current base directory is "/opt/btech/probe/share/locale/WA"
current LC_MESSAGES locale is "fake"
gettext("Error") ==> "Ḗřřǿř"
```

Now, when I compile this dynamically, it doesn't work. Neither on the target device, nor locally on my PC (with the files installed the same way). The `setlocale()` call fails, returning a `NULL` pointer and setting errno to `ENOENT` (file not found). At the point of `setlocale()` I haven't pointed `bindtextdomain()` to where my files are at, but switching the calls around doesn't help.

Am I doing things wrong, is my working example from above wrong and shouldn't really work? Do I need locale definitions for anything I call `setlocale()` on, even for `LC_MESSAGES`?

This is the source of the test binary:

```
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *l = setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "fake");

    printf("setlocale() returned \"%s\"\n", l);

    bind_textdomain_codeset("ewe", "UTF-8");
    bindtextdomain("ewe", "/opt/btech/probe/share/locale/WA");
    textdomain("ewe");

    printf("current textdomain is \"%s\"\n", textdomain(NULL));
    printf("current base directory is \"%s\"\n", bindtextdomain(textdomain(NULL), NULL));
    printf("current LC_MESSAGES locale is \"%s\"\n", setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, NULL));
    printf("gettext(\"Error\") ==> \"%s\"\n", gettext("Error"));

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output when compiled dynamically (either for target or host):

```
setlocale() returned "(null)"
current textdomain is "ewe"
current base directory is "/opt/btech/probe/share/locale/WA"
current LC_MESSAGES locale is "C"
gettext("Error") ==> "Error"
```

*EDIT*: Compiling the test binary as static on my host (x64 Linux) also makes it work, so there is something special with the static compile.

Additional question: Can I force gettext to load a specific mo file directly?  Basically I would like to have a replacement for `bindtextdomain()` that takes a file name argument instead.

*EDIT 2*: So, I eventually found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564879/2501078) saying that I can get `gettext()` to load any translation as long as I have a valid `setlocale()` call first. So, my current workaround is to actually generate a `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive` containing only the `en_US` locale, calling `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "en_US"); setenv("LANGUAGE", "fake");`, which ends up loading the correct message catalog. Still feels like an ugly workaround, and I still don't understand why the static link works without it.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "");` with the proper environment variables?

Comment: This is an embedded system where I run without the environment variables set. I load the language to use (i.e., the locale to set) from a configuration file when the program starts up.

Comment: Doing a `setenv("LC_MESSAGES", "fake")` first and replacing the setlocale call with `setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "")` still fails the same way as doing the `setlocale()` call directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (an embedded system where I don't have much control on the root file system) and I found this workaround to work:

- Put all translations in `/<mydir>/lang/`
- The `SYS_LC_MESSAGES` can be generated with `localedef`. I made one from the C locale on my system and copied it to each target directory

  ```
  mkdir output
  localedef -f UTF-8 -i /usr/share/i18n/locales/C  output/mylocale
  cp output/mylocale/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES <mydir>/lang/ENG/LC_MESSAGES/
  ```
- Set the `LOCPATH` to `<mydir>`
- Debug things with `strace` to see which files it is trying to open.

This is my final file layout:

```
<mydir>
├── lang
│   ├── ENG
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── SYS_LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── mac.mo
│   ├── FRE
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── SYS_LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── mac.mo
│   ├── GER
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── SYS_LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── mac.mo
│   ├── ITA
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── SYS_LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── mac.mo
│   ├── SPA
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── SYS_LC_MESSAGES
│   │       └── mac.mo
```

This is the code snippet:

```
putenv("LOCPATH=/<mydir>/lang");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");  
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "ENG");
bindtextdomain("mac", "/<mydir>/lang");
textdomain("mac");      
gettext("Hello world");
```

This is a hack, the proper solution would be to generate the locales correctly.